# Delphi 2010. Не компилируется файл fs6.dpk

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-2010

> '[DCC Fatal Error] fs14.dpk(59): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'fs_ipascal.pas
>
> Library path: '$(BDS)\lib;$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports;$(BDS)\Imports;$(BDS)\Lib\Indy10;$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp;$(BDS)\include;c:\delphi_lib\fastreport 4\libd14;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressBars 5;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressBars 6;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressCommon Library;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressCore Library;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressDataController;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressDBTree Suite;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressDocking Library;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressEditors Library 3;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressEditors Library 5;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressExport Library;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressFlowChart;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressGDI+ Library;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressLayout Control;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressLayout Control 2;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressLibrary;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressMasterView;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressMemData;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressNavBar;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressNavBar 2;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressPageControl 2;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressPrinting System;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressPrinting System 4;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressQuantumGrid 3;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressQuantumGrid 4;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressQuantumGrid 5;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressQuantumGrid 6;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\ExpressVerticalGrid;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\XP Theme Manager;C:\Delphi_Lib\DevExpress v47 and DxAutoInstaller v1.81\de47Src\Delphi 2010 Library\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Comp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Comp\ODAC;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Comp\ODAC\Lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Comp\ODAC\DbToolsInterfaces;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Comp\ODAC\Source;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Comp\ODAC\Help;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Demos;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Comp\ODAC\Images;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Comp\ODAC\Include;C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD6;C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD11;C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD12;C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD15;C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD14;C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Bpl
>   '
>
> Package output directory: C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Bpl
>
> DCP output directory: $(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp
>
> Browsing path: $(BDS)\SOURCE\WIN32\VCL;$(BDS)\source\Win32\rtl\common;$(BDS)\SOURCE\WIN32\RTL\SYS;$(BDS)\source\Win32\rtl\win;$(BDS)\SOURCE\WIN32\WEBSNAP;$(BDS)\source\ToolsAPI;$(BDS)\SOURCE\WIN32\IBX;$(BDS)\source\Win32\Internet;$(BDS)\SOURCE\WIN32\PROPERTY EDITORS;$(BDS)\source\Win32\soap;$(BDS)\SOURCE\WIN32\XML;$(BDS)\source\Win32\db;$(BDS)\source\Indy\Indy10\Core;$(BDS)\source\Indy\Indy10\System;$(BDS)\source\Indy\Indy10\Protocols;$(BDS)\source\database;C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD14;
>
> Debug DCU path: '$(BDS)\lib\Debug;$(BDS)\Lib\Debug\Indy10'

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD6;
C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD11;
C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD12;
C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD15;
C:\Delphi_Lib\fastreport 4\LibD14;
```

Оставьте только папку, соответствующую Вашей версии Delphi.